# I'm using cocos creator 1.1, I don't know how to install socket.io to the project, can anyone help me?

Tags: socket.io, game-engine, cocos2d-js

I'm using cocos creator 1.1, I don't know how to install socket io to the project, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example with two solutions in the "example-cases" from the Cocos Creator development team.

In this version, they import socket.io as a plugin using `socket-io.js.meta`:

```
{
  "ver": "1.0.2",
  "uuid": "ccfc9583-4ec4-4955-a4aa-85021dcea346",
  "isPlugin": true,
  "subMetas": {}
}
```

https://github.com/cocos-creator/example-cases/tree/0d7b1f8d1123a9ee6d73484c1cad465d59fd2199/assets/cases/05_scripting/11_network

And in this version, they use `require`

```
if (!window.io)
    window.io = require('socket-io');
```

https://github.com/cocos-creator/example-cases/tree/5e6e7f75eee21033ba2d609d693dd47fcc9d2bf5/assets/cases/05_scripting/11_network